# change hasManyThrough() relation attribute name through accessor

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, has-many-through

I have 3 Models

- Campaign PK(id)
- CampaignMedium FK(campaign_id)
- AccountReceivable FK(campaign_medium_id) **(has an amount column)**

Controller function:

```
public function all()
{
    return Campaign::with(['customer', 'receivedPayments'])->get();
}
```

In Campaign Model relationships are defined as follows:

```
public function customer() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}

public function accountReceivable()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(AccountReceivable::class, CampaignMedium::class);
}

public function receivedPayments()
{
    return $this->accountReceivable()
    ->selectRaw('sum(account_receivables.amount) as total')
    ->groupBy('campaign_id');
}

public function getReceivedPaymentsAttribute()
{
    if (!array_key_exists('receivedPayments', $this->relations)) {
        $this->load('receivedPayments');
    }

    $relation = $this->getRelation('receivedPayments')->first();

    return ($relation) ? $relation->total : 0;
}
```

Final Output:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "example",
        "image": "campaign/90375849f6c3cc6b0e542a0e3e6295b890375849f6c3cc6b0e542a0e3e6295b8.jpeg",
        "amount": 10,
        "description": "saddsa",
        "start_at": "2019-02-12 00:00:00",
        "end_at": "2019-02-12 00:00:00",
        "due_at": "2019-02-12 00:00:00",
        "status": "active",
        "customer": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test",
            "email": "info@test.com",
            "image": "customer/ec812116705ff3ae85298234fe6c4e97ec812116705ff3ae85298234fe6c4e97.jpeg",
            "address": "sample address"
        },
        "received_payments": [
            {
                "total": "700",
                "laravel_through_key": 8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "example",
        "image": "campaign/fff9fadc92a809513dc28134379851aafff9fadc92a809513dc28134379851aa.jpeg",
        "amount": 10,
        "description": "saddsa",
        "start_at": "2019-02-12 00:00:00",
        "end_at": "2019-02-12 00:00:00",
        "due_at": "2019-02-12 00:00:00",
        "status": "active",
        "customer": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test",
            "email": "info@test.com",
            "image": "customer/ec812116705ff3ae85298234fe6c4e97ec812116705ff3ae85298234fe6c4e97.jpeg",
            "address": "sample address"
        },
        "received_payments": []
    }
]
}
```

summary: trying to get the sum of AccountReceivable amount attribute, which is working fine but the **getReceivedPaymentsAttribute()** isn't working which needs to return the total value only. also can anyone please help me to explain why laravel_through_key is added with received_payments?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to use an attribute modifier to modify a relation this way. You are overriding the expected result of `receivedPayments()`. You might be better off to define a separate attribute like so:

```php
public function getSumReceivedPaymentsAttribute()
{
    // ...your code... 
}
```

Now you can access the attribute using `$model->sum_received_payments` or always preload it using:

```php
// model.php
protected $appends = ['sum_received_payments'];
```

Comment: it's throwing an exception: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string

Comment: where did it throw that and on which function?

Comment: on getSumReceivedPaymentsAttribute() function

Comment: your attribute function is generating the following query: **select sum(`account_receivables`.`amount`) as aggregate from `account_receivables` inner join `campaign_mediums` on `campaign_mediums`.`id` = `account_receivables`.`campaign_medium_id` group by `campaign_id`**

Comment: where as the previous relation was generating: **select sum(account_receivables.amount) as total, `campaign_mediums`.`campaign_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `account_receivables` inner join `campaign_mediums` on `campaign_mediums`.`id` = `account_receivables`.`campaign_medium_id` where `campaign_mediums`.`campaign_id` in (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22) group by `campaign_id`**

Comment: hm i guess you can rename your function to `getSumReceivedPaymentsAttribute()` so that it doesnt conflict with the `receivedPayments()`. Although i've got the feeling that your solution will probably query each model separately.

Comment: as per your solution i removed **receivedPayments** argument in controller **with()** function and created a `protected $appends = ['received_payments']` in campaign model. But again I am getting the same results as mentioned in final output. ` getReceivedPaymentsAttribute()` accessor isn't being accessed at all. i am unable to mutate the output of `receivedPayments()` relation through accessor. Also $append will always return the value in every collection which is not ideal in my case as i am using resources to output my model, that's why i am using `with()` to get the collection.

Comment: well I dont think you can override that `receivedPayments()` relation, so your `$appends` must point to a differently named property